# React-Native: Date.parse() fails with an offset of "+0000"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to parse a string to a Date in React-Native (With Typescript). However, Date.parse() returns `NaN` if the timezone offset is `+0000`:

`console.log(Date.parse('2019-03-05T12:15:42.810+0000'));`

> `NaN`

If I add a colon to the offset, it works as expected:

`console.log(Date.parse('2019-03-05T12:15:42.810+00:00'));`

> `1551788142810`

From the docs and examples I found I was under the impression that both formats should work.

I'm testing with android only.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you testing under iOS?

Comment: @mayakwd Android only. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Native using JavaScriptCore under the hood, which implementation differs from V8, it implements [ECMAScript as ECMAScript-262](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore) specification.

Representation of a date time string in ECMAScript-262 - simplified version of ISO8601, and it's described in [ECMAScript 262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) specification as:  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Where `Z` represents UTC offset in format `+` or `-` and time offset in format `HH:mm`.

For example:

- `+09:00`
- `-04:00`.